# Преобразование типа переменной str в byte с сохранением значений Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, int

Есть динамически генерируемая переменная типа *str* содержащая "10101011". Как преобразовать её в тип *byte* сохранив при этом значение в строке, чтобы физически был записан 1 байт в переменной?

(знаю что питон для этого не очень подходит)

Comment: Строго говоря, в Python нет типа byte

Comment: В Питоне есть тип `byte`, только он далеко спрятан: [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes), [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray), [array.array](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html#module-array).

Comment: `s = '10101011'; b = bytes((int(s, 2),))` -> `b'\xab'`. `b[0]` -> `171`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял:

```py
string = "10101011"
ch = chr(int(string, 2))
print(ch)
```

Вывод:

```
«
```

То есть преобразуем в число (с базой 2), потом это число преобразуем в символ с таким кодом.

Comment: Отмечу чисто формально, что тут не совсем тип `byte`, если понимать под этим класс `bytes`, впрочем, скорее всего, автор все же такого ответа, как у @CrazyElf,  хотел в своем вопросе:-)

Answer (score 2):

Как дополнение к ответу @CrazyElf (стало интересно покопаться) - не все так просто в Python при желании "чтобы физически был записан 1 байт в переменной" (не очень понятная формулировка, кстати, в вопросе).

Посмотрим на количество байт, нужное для той или иной записи.
Видим, что целое число `int` длиной в один байт займет 28 байт на самом деле (да и длиной в два байта столько же займут).
Перевод в тип `bytes` строки автора создаст тип `byte`, и займет уже 41 байт.
(1 символ в байтовом виде займет 34 байт, как видим далее, т.е. каждый символ добавляет байт к базе в 33 байта.

Видим также, что у @CrazyElf идет работа с `int`, а результат - 'str', как автор и хотел (с длиной в 74 байта, впрочем, пустая строка займет столько же).

```
import sys
string = "10101011"

# Просто число для примера (все восемь единиц в байте)
a = 255
print("постороннее число в один байт", a, type (a), sys.getsizeof(a))
# Печатает: постороннее число в один байт 255 <class 'int'> 28

# Строка автора в `int` виде 
b= int(string)
print('целое', b, type (b), sys.getsizeof(b))
# Печатает: целое 10101011 <class 'int'> 28

# Строка автора в `bytes` виде
by = bytes(string, 'ascii')
print('байт', by, type (by), sys.getsizeof(by))
# Печатает: байт b'10101011' <class 'bytes'> 41

# Просто один символ для примера
с = b'1'
print('байт - 1 символ', с, type (с), sys.getsizeof(с))
# Печатает: байт - 1 символ b'1' <class 'bytes'> 34

# Преобразование в целое из ответа @CrazyElf 
d = int(string, 2)
print('целое по базе', d, type (d), sys.getsizeof(d))
# Печатает: целое по базе 171 <class 'int'> 28

# Дальнейшее преобразование из ответа @CrazyElf
ch = chr(int(string, 2))
print("символ с кодом", ch, type (ch), sys.getsizeof(ch))
# Печатает: символ с кодом « <class 'str'> 74
```

Comment: Ну вы тут про внутреннее хранение данных питоном. А если автор хотел куда-то дальше этот символ передать, например, записать в файл или передать по каналам связи, то это будет именно один байт

Comment: Я потому и предположил, что вы правильно ответили, но вообще сложно автора понять. Кстати, как-то я удивился, что тип `bytes` каждый бит в отдельном байте хранит.

Comment: В "Просто один бит для примера" ошибка. Это 1 байт. Занимает столько же, сколько bytes([int(string, 2)]) -> 34

Comment: @Lecron, спасибо, верно - ошибка. Это один символ. Попытка вписать `FF' завершается использованием двух байтов. Исправил текст.

Comment: @Сергей chr(255) = 'ÿ'

Comment: @Lecron, извините, это вы к чему про "chr(255) = 'ÿ'"? Я просто о том, что вообще FF - один байт, но b'FF' не означает один байт, а чтобы распознать это как один байт, надо писать "b'\xFF' (полагаю вы это знаете, а вот я поизучал дополнительно сейчас:-))